# Get content from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

My screen contains 2 buttons, each one opens the same `<Modal>` component, but the `<View>` inside it changes depending on the button clicked.

For example :

If I click the first button, a text input will be shown into the modal ; If I click the second button, a switch will be shown into the modal.

I've made a modal component (Modal.tsx) :

```
export default class Modal extends Component {

  public render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.modal} >
        {this.props.children}
      <View>
    )
  };
}

// Specific modal implementation with TextInput
const ModalWithTextInput = props => (
  <TextInput
    value={props.someValue}
  />
)


// Specific modal implementation with Switch
const ModalWithSwitch = props => (
  <Switch
    value={props.someValue}
  />
)
```

And now in my 5-button-screen (ButtonsScreen.tsx), I open the right modal depending on the button clicked :

```
openTextModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalVisible: true, modalType: 'text' });
}

openSwitchModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalVisible: true, modalType: 'switch' });
}
```

These functions are called with, for example, `onPress={this.openTextModal}`

Finally, I render the modal as this :

```
renderModal = (type) => {
    if (type === 'text') {
        return <ModalWithTextInput someValue="default text" />
    }

    if (type === 'switch') {
        return <ModalWithSwitch someValue={false}/>
    }
}
```

To be able to do something like :

```
<Modal
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    animationType={'slide'}
    onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal()}>
    <View style={style.modalContainer}>
        <View style={style.innerContainer}>
            <View>
                {this.renderModal(this.state.modalType)}
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
</View>
```

When I try to do `onPress={this.openTextModal}`, the modal opens with no content. What's wrong ?

Anyone can please help ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me what styles you have applied to modalContainer and innerContainer?

Comment: Of course! modalContainer: flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'. innerContainer: flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving `flex: 1` to modelContainer and innerContainer, but it is not getting applied on `this.renderModal(this.state.modalType)`, because you have wrapped it with another View with no flex. Either you remove that or give it a `flex: 1`, modal should appear. I guess this should work fine.

```
<View style={style.modalContainer}>
   <View style={style.innerContainer}>
            {this.renderModal(this.state.modalType)}
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: It's weird... it effectively was something wrong with the style but it didn't fix the problem. Thank you anyway !